# How to display the xml file existing content in datagrid, and can be edittable and save

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I'm still learning about WPF, C# and xml file.
I have xml file with existing content. 
What I want to do is :

1. display the xml file content in datagrid
2. when the xml file is
   displaying in datagrid, user can edit the content
3. after user edit the
   content, write the new data inside same xml file
   but I am stuck at 1st step.

I want to show something like this (example only, not real data):

[image]

- File Name = Eqpt ID
- File Location = Equip Opn
- name = bin code
- surname = bin description,
- phone no = bin quality

and so on..

but the problem is, when I run the application, it come out like this
[image]
here is what I had been tried :

```
string sampleXMLFile = FilePath.XmlBinCode;
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(sampleXMLFile);
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
dataGrid_ConfigurableRejectBinCode.ItemsSource = dataView;
```

here is the preview of my xml file :

[image]

here is the preview of my XAML :

```
 <DockPanel Background="White">
    <Button Content="Load File" Click="LoadXmlFile_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_ConfigurableRejectBinCode"
              DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Code" Binding="{Binding BinCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[BinDescription].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Quality" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[BinQuality].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pick" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Pick].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vision Station" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[VisionStation].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vision IO" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[VisionIO].Value}"/>-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

How to display the xml data like the image above, like I wanted? please excuse my language since English is not my mother tongue.
and please help me, thank you

Comment: Can you post the XAML in which you create the DataGrid?

Comment: @farfetched I already edit and added the XAML screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I already found the way to display it, here it's how I did it

make class and bind everything the details want to show inside XAML control.
this is the XAML

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Eqpt ID"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Equip Opn"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding EqptID}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding EquipOpn}"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="DataGrid_BinDefinition" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding BinDefinition}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Code" Binding="{Binding BinCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Description" Binding="{Binding BinDescription}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bin Quality" Binding="{Binding BinQuality}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Pick" Binding="{Binding Pick}"/>
            <mahApps:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Vision Station" Binding="{Binding VisionStation}" Maximum="3" Minimum="1"/>
            <mahApps:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Vision IO" Binding="{Binding VisionIO}" Maximum="32" Minimum="1"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ButtonAddRow" Content="Add Row" Click="ButtonAddRow_Click"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ButtonDeleteRow" Content="Delete Row" Click="ButtonDeleteRow_Click"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="ButtonSaveFile" Content="Save File" Click="ButtonSaveFile_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

then class that bind the control

```
 [Serializable]
public partial class XmlBinDefinitionModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [XmlElement("EqptID")]
    private string eqptID;
    public string EqptID
    {
        get { return eqptID; }
        set
        {
            if (eqptID != value)
            {
                eqptID = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EqptID));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("EquipOpn")]
    private string equipOpn;
    public string EquipOpn
    {
        get { return equipOpn; }
        set
        {
            if (equipOpn != value)
            {
                equipOpn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EquipOpn));
            }
        }
    }

    private List<BinDefinitionModel> binDefinition;
    public List<BinDefinitionModel> BinDefinition
    {
        get { return binDefinition; }
        set
        {
            if (binDefinition != value)
            {
                binDefinition = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BinDefinition));
            }
        }
    }
}//end public partial class XmlBinDefinitionModel 

public partial class BinDefinitionModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [XmlElement("BinCode")]
    private string binCode;
    public string BinCode
    {
        get { return binCode; }
        set
        {
            if (binCode != value)
            {
                binCode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BinCode));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("BinDescription")]
    private string binDescription;
    public string BinDescription
    {
        get { return binDescription; }
        set
        {
            if (binDescription != value)
            {
                binDescription = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BinDescription));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("BinQuality")]
    private string binQuality;
    public string BinQuality
    {
        get { return binQuality; }
        set
        {
            if (binQuality != value)
            {
                binQuality = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BinQuality));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Pick")]
    private string pick;
    public string Pick
    {
        get { return pick; }
        set
        {
            if (pick != value)
            {
                pick = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Pick));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("VisionStation")]
    private string visionStation;
    public string VisionStation
    {
        get { return visionStation; }
        set
        {
            if (visionStation != value)
            {
                visionStation = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(VisionStation));
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("VisionIO")]
    private string visionIO;
    public string VisionIO
    {
        get { return visionIO; }
        set
        {
            if (visionIO != value)
            {
                visionIO = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(VisionIO));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then at code behind

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(FilePath.XmlBinCode); //load the file
            xmlBinDefinitionModel.EqptID = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("EqptID").InnerText;
            xmlBinDefinitionModel.EquipOpn = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("EquipOpn").InnerText;
            xmlBinDefinitionModel.BinDefinition = new List<BinDefinitionModel>();
            XmlNodeList binCodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("BinCode");
            XmlNodeList binDescriptionList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("BinDescription");
            XmlNodeList binQualityList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("BinQuality");
            XmlNodeList pickList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Pick");
            XmlNodeList visionStationList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("VisionStation");
            XmlNodeList visionIOList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("VisionIO");
            for (int i = 0; i < binCodeList.Count; i++)
            {
                xmlBinDefinitionModel.BinDefinition.Add(new BinDefinitionModel
                {
                    BinCode = binCodeList[i].InnerText.Remove(0,2),
                    BinDescription = binDescriptionList[i].InnerText,
                    BinQuality = binQualityList[i].InnerText,
                    Pick = pickList[i].InnerText,
                    VisionStation = visionStationList[i].InnerText,
                    VisionIO = visionStationList[i].InnerText
                });
            }
```